# Jquery fadeIn fadeOut list of divs with active divs

Tags: jquery, menu, bind, unbind, fading

What I'm trying to achieve is a list of links with some separate divs.
at the moment the fading is working but is "jumping on click" and the active in both `<ul id="links">` and `#description` doesn't work properly.
Could you help me please?

here is my eg.:

http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/100/

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with the same ID. Change it to use a class of description instead of ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H, I suggest you do this.

Also changed from descriptions to classes as the ideal code requires unique ids per page

http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/104/

html

```
<ul id="links">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul><br/><br/>
<div id="description">
<ul class="descriptions">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul class="descriptions">
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>

<ul class="descriptions">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="descriptions">
    <li>4</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
<ul class="descriptions">
    <li>5</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul></div>
```

CSS

```
.active{color:red}

#description{position:relative}
.descriptions{position:absolute; top:0px;}
```

JS

```
$("ul#links li").unbind().bind('click', function(e) {
    if (e)
        e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $("ul.descriptions").fadeOut();

    var index = $(this).index();;
    $("ul.descriptions").eq(index).fadeIn();

    if (!e) e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
}, function(e) {
    $("ul.descriptions").stop().fadeOut();
});



$("ul.descriptions").hide();
if ($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
    $(this).next().removeClass('active');
}

$('ul#links li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul#links li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: only the first child you mean? not sure I understand you but is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/110/

Comment: the fist child visible the <ul class="descriptions">
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>

Comment: ahhh ok here you go http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/115/
i removed the hide from javascript and put it in css then set the first one as visible

Comment: the problem was the fact that you added <a> tag and you tried to get its index where you need it's parent's index.

here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/148/

Answer (score 0):

here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/mdamC/102/

Comment: thanks for this, but the activs are all red! can we avoid this?

Comment: sorry mate, how can I make the fist child visible?